# Wifi Router shuts down when connecting

Tags: networking, internet

Here is my issue which is very strange and I've tested it various times along the past two weeks,

WiFi router is working very smooth and every device in the household is connected to it with no issues what so ever.

Now here's the messy part, once I start the machine with Ubuntu and connect to the WiFi, every other device including the machine gets disconnected and there's no WiFi signal from the router, until I re-plug the router.

After that, here's the most strange part, the connection becomes so slow only on the machine that you can't even load a google web page.

Sorry, but I'm Ubuntu newbie, and don't know if there are any requirements that I should perform.

Comment: Sound like a power problem of your wifi chipset on your router. Could you repeat the same issue with different router or cable connection?

Comment: Already done, same thing happened.

Comment: I know this kind of issue from a former customer. He installed his private NAS with DHCP enabled, so every device is thinking the small SOHO NAS was DHCP, DNS and gateway. We all know a embedded device will struggle with over 200 devices on one LAN port. ,,, Maybe your ubuntu has something like a wrong configured dnsmasq running? Try to find it with 'traceroute askubuntu.com' from any other system in the net before and after plug in the ubuntu. (A broken DNS will be enough) ... on a linux the package 'mtr' is a good package to see a change.

Comment: Can you repeat it with booting from Ubuntu Live USB? Does the same thing happen?

Comment: It might be, that your Ubuntu is messing up with dhcp protocol. Can you check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/874930/isc-dhcp-server-disabling-and-configuring

Answer (score 0):

As @user79267 indicated, an OS reinstall is an option, but you could simply accomplish the same thing by trying the Ubuntu from USB without installing it. You don't want to lose everything.

If the WiFi behavior doesn't change, you may consider replacing that WiFi adapter.
It may simply generate noise on the network causing the router to enter a protection mode or simply crash.